# How to make a signup and login form acessible on everypage that i may use modals Django 1.8

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have implemented both login and signup forms in my Django app. Currently they are being rendered to signup.html and login.html pages by corresponding views as below

```
def user_login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        #do some authentication stuff login as stay on the page
        login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if login_form.is_valid():
            cleaned_form_data = login_form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(username = cleaned_form_data['username'],
                                password = cleaned_form_data['password'])
            if user is not None:
                #proceed to login if active
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request,user)
                    #return HttpResponse('Successfully Logged In')
                    messages.success(request,'Login successfull')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Inactive User')

            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid Login')

    else:
        login_form = LoginForm()

    template = 'accounts/login.html'        
    context = {'form':login_form,}
    return render(request,template,context)

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save(commit = False)
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            new_user.set_password(password)             
            new_user.save()
            return render(request,'accounts/reg_success.html',{'new_user':new_user,})

    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
        template = 'accounts/register.html'
        context = {'form':form,}
        return render(request,template,context)
```

How do i implement this so that i have have the forms sent to every page and can user Javascript Modals to login and signup users. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but I think there are 2 solutions:

1. Load the modal content using AJAX GET to `user_login`
2. Use a `base.html` where it contains the modal contents, then every page can extend the base page using {% extends 'base.html' %}